# Why is my cat not losing weight?

Tags: cats, health, weight

I've been feeding her a quarter less than the usual pouchful,  and less dry food too, for a month. She lost weight from her hips and has reached a plateau, I guess, but that is just a guess.

The vet had advised me that she needs to lose a couple of kilos. But she only met my cat once. So she does not know her that well.

She runs around our large flat sometimes. So she is not massive and sedentary. Some cats are so slender, but not mine. Am I to assume that, like some humans (me, anyway) she is naturally a bit fat round her middle and shoulders and that I have nothing to worry about? She is a neutered, indoor cat.

Comment: How big is the cat and what's her weight?

Comment: Also, what brand/flavor of food are you feeding and how much (especially the dry food)? Different foods have different caloric densities and can affect weight loss/gain.

Answer (score 6):

Like humans cats will come in a range of natural weights - being 2kg over the "recommended" is quite a lot though. When my boy needed to lose weight (~1kg) I had better success with swapping his food out for a low calorie version. I also upped the amount of time I spent playing with him in order to increase the amount of exercise he was getting. It took a few months but his weight did come down.

Edit: Since you mention she is an indoor only cat that is helpful in that it means she is not going out  and supplementing her food by hunting etc. So you can control her intake. That being the case I would go with the low calorie diet and if you can work in a good 20mins of active okay a day. If you can work the play in before a meal even better as this fits the hunt - eat - sleep cycle they would have naturally.